# setVariables() many to many relation symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a many to many relation between let's say entityA and entityB and I will use embeeded forms in order to add the attribute of entityA in the form of entityB as follows

```
$builder ->add('entityAs', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'xxxBundle:EntityA',
              'property' => 'name',
              'multiple' => false,
            ));}
```

When I set 'multiple' to true, everything is OK.
But when I set it to false, I get the following error

```
Property "entityAs" is not public in class "xxx\Entity\EntityB". Maybe you should create the method "setEntityAs()"?
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual the property entityAs in your EntityB class is not public (protected or private). So  you have to write (or generate) a setter for it: setEntityAs($entityAs)

multiple true may work, as I think (not sure) it uses the addXxx Setter. Proof me, if you have an addEntityAs Method in your EntityB Class?

Buuuuut, if you have a many to many relation, why you would set multiple to false?

Comment: yes I do have a addEntityA() but when I added setEntityAs($entityAs), I get this error : Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 519 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 48

Comment: Please, some more code (your addEntityA and the new setter method) as update on your question.

Comment: That's exactly the point. @Pazi I set it to false because I will use it in some other cases like a many to one entity.

Comment: I found the solution: I have to add 'property_path' => false, and every thing becomes fine. thank u @Pazi

Comment: Are you sure, that your edits in the embedded form get saved?